# Android build error "failed to create JavaTypeInfo for class" :AndroidX.Core.View.Accessibility ManagerCompat/... in Xamarin Forms

Tags: android, .net, .net-core, xamarin.forms

[image]Following this tutorial https://github.com/jsuarezruiz/netmaui-travel-app-challenge , I downloaded the application without making any changes in visual studio 2022.

When I build the application, I get the following error:

`Severity Code Description Project Project File Line Status suppressed Error Reference assemblies for .NETCore,Version=v5.0 are not found. To resolve this problem, install the Developer Pack (SDK or Compatibility Pack) for this version of the .NET Framework or redeploy the application. To download the .NET Framework developer packages, go to https://aka.ms/msbuild/developerpacks TravelApp.UWP`                
What is the possible solution? I am compiling it in visual studio 2022.

I already tried to install the packages. In fact when I go to windows to dotnet SDK it tells me that it is already installed, but I still get the same error.[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have cloned the project in the link you provided in my Visual Studio 2022. And there is two project in it. One is Maui and the other is Xamarin Forms. I build the Maui one. And after I delete the following code in the .csproj file. The project build successfuly.

```
    <ItemGroup Condition="$(TargetFramework.Contains('-windows'))">
        <!-- Required - WinUI does not yet have buildTransitive for everything -->
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.WindowsAppSDK" Version="1.0.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Graphics.Win2D" Version="1.0.0.30" />
    </ItemGroup>
```

And according to the error message you provided. The cause should be you missed the .NET framework SDK (. NET core, v5.0) on your machine. You can refer to [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49272241/17455524)
in this case [which has the similar error message as yours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49268779/the-reference-assemblies-for-framework-netcore-version-v5-0-were-not-found).

I have checked the **C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETCore\v5.0** path on my machine. It is here. So you can check it.

Hope this can help you. Good luck!